# Buggy CSS Behavior in a UIWebView: font-size is misinterpreted

Tags: javascript, ios, css, iphone, uiwebview

My app contains a `UIWebView` where I want to control the text size via buttons.

The source HTML is very messy and from a pre-HTML5 era. I managed to write a JavaScript hack that performs pretty well on the iPad and 4"-inches iPhone and iPod Touch but doesn't work great on 3,5" devices.

I’m debugging the HMTL via Safari (via the Development > iPhone Simulator menu that I’ve just discovered) and it seems the CSS interpretation of Safari Mobile is weird.

This is an extract of the HTML:

```
<html>  
  <head>        
    <meta id="viewport" name="viewport" content="width=device-width-20, initial-scale=0.8">
    <style type="text/css">
      ... some inline style...
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    ...
    <span style="font-size: 26px;">
      Bla bla bla
      ...
    </span>
    ...
  </body>
</html>
```

This is 2 screenshots from Safari's web inspector:

The first one shows rules:

[image: Safari Inspector Screenshot: CSS rules]

The second one shows how text is displayed:

[image: Safari Inspector Screenshot: CSS Applied rules]

How can you explain the 26px font-size is ignored and the 18px font-size is displayed?

Comment: Is the `font-size: 18px` applied by an `!important` rule in a stylesheet? `!important` stylesheet rules supercede inline styles (except when the inline style has `!important`).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder unfortunately, it’s not.

Comment: Could you create a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) that demonstrates the problem? Or if you can't make it work in a jsfiddle, a link to your site will have to do.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seemed to come from the following line:

```
<meta id="viewport" name="viewport" content="width=device-width-20, initial-scale=0.8">
```

`device-width-20`is not a recognized token (and I think the developer who wrote it meant (`device-width` − 20px).

As it turns out, simplifying this line to the following was enough for iOS 7:

```
<meta id="viewport" name="viewport" content="width=initial-scale=1.0">
```

cf. [this doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-7.0/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013202-CH1-SW75) for more information about how iOS deals with the viewport.